# Is the sharing interface in many stock iOS7 apps built in, or custom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, social-networking, sharing

As the title says, I wanted to know about the sharing interface that you see in Safari or Photos.  Is it custom?

If it is built-in instead, what is it officially called so I can look up the Apple documentation on it.

For reference, this is what I am referring to (in this case from Safari):
[image: Image of Color bars showing the sharing interface at the bottom]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to get well acquainted with [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and what you can do with it.

There's also a [sample project and NSChat transcript that you can find on my github](https://github.com/dautermann/ActivityViewControllerTest).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  I knew it was probably built in somehow, but I just didn't know what they called it.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe I heard it referred to informally as "the share sheet" during a WWDC session by an Apple engineer.

Comment: That makes me feel a bit better about calling it the Sharing Interface.  I have not seen that WWDC session though, so methinks I'll look that up too.